# Does ruby have a log viewer?

Tags: ruby, logging, log-viewer, rails-agnostic

Is there a log viewer for displaying Ruby log files from any of its loggers (be it l4r or their basic logger)? Some kind of gui app that opens a log file and can support simple queries such as INFO only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache Chainsaw V2 can load regular text log files, allowing you to seach, colorize & filter using expressions (like level == info)...just configure Chainsaw using a LogFilePatternReceiver, and your file's log contents will show up in a tab in the UI (the receiver does support tailing).

Chinsaw V2 is written in Java, but the receiver will parse any log file and Chainsaw will display the events.

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot about that one.

Answer (score 6):

In *nix, `less` is my first choice for log file viewing.  It has, among other things:

- Regular expression search (<kbd>/</kbd>)
- "Follow" (<kbd>F</kbd>), which shows new lines as they come in
- Scrolling via up/down/PgUp/PgDn/etc.
- A filter that shows only lines matching a regular expression (&)

Comment: Even on Windows, one can install http://www.cygwin.com/ and feel as if  he has a decent OS. :P

Answer (score 0):

[splunk](http://www.splunk.com/)  is very cool. you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to remember from an earlier question that you're on Windows, right? Logging is a universal thing -- not specific to Ruby. So as far as I know there's no log viewer "for Ruby." But there are tons of log viewers in general that can be used with Ruby, Apache, or whatever.

I'm not too familiar with the Windows log viewer scene, but [Googling "windows tail utility"](http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&ie=UTF-8&q=windows+tail+utility) turned up many options. Some of them are free.

(`tail` is a standard Unix command for monitoring log files. So the above search is for Windows apps that provide the same functionality.)